# Python Unicode - u prefix

Tags: python, list, unicode

I have list:

```
['data','oracle','typical']
```

I am writing a code that will write a list to file:

```
self.file.write(unicode(self.contentText))
```

However in file, I see:

```
[u'data',u'oracle',u'typical']
```

How can fix this? I don't want to see `u`

Comment: You writing it in unicode form. So you should see `u`. Otherwise just use `self.file.write((self.contentText))`

Comment: @GLHF if I dont use unicode, I get error: 

`TypeError: must be unicode, not list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using Python 2, and converting a `str` to a unicode string. So, the `u` will show up indicating that the result is Unicode. If you don't want to see `u`s everywhere, switch to Python 3.

Comment: it's a list and not a str. Hence need to unicode it. Else I'll get error : `TypeError: must be unicode, not list`

Comment: @Rakanid you can only write strings and string-like objects to regular files, not lists, dicts, tuples, etc. If you need to store more complex data like that, consider using [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html).